# Chart js: bar width

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I want to display data in chart js (version 3.7.1) with horizontal bar chart. Data are loading from backend. My problem is with widht of bar. When I have only a few records, bars are very thick.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCOr9.png) When I have a lot of records (for example 1000) bars are very narrow and are missing label.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcWe8.png) How can you see in images.
I would like have still the same widht for bars and if is a lot of records enable scroll.

There is my code:

```
  createConfig(config: ChartConfigDto): ChartConfiguration {
    return {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: config.labels,
        datasets:
            config.datasets.map((dataset, index) => ({
              label: dataset.label,
              backgroundColor: `${CHART_COLORS[index]}`,
              borderColor: `${CHART_COLORS[index]}`,
              data: dataset.data,
              barThickness: 'flex',
            }))
      },
      options: {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        plugins: {
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Sites',
          },
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
          },
        },
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          x: {
            stacked: true,
            position: 'top',
          },
          y: {
            stacked: true,
            grid: {
              display: false,
            },
          }
        },
      },
    }
  }
```

```
        <div class="modal-body">
          <canvas appChart [config]="config"></canvas>
        </div>
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70823795/2358409

Answer (score 2):

There are two properties you can use to achieve.

- [barThickness](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barthickness)
- [maxBarThickness](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#maxbarthickness)

You can use **maxBarThickness** property in the dataset.

Here I'm attaching [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs-bar-cahrt-cqhxdv) demo

Comment: maxBarThickness works well only for a few records.
When i use  barThickness for a lot of records, it creates:
https://ibb.co/72cgwb7 and are still missing some labels.